# View Holder pattern , how to handle Bitmap in adapter?

Tags: android, adapter

In the API demo , there is an example of an effecient list adapter in which all the bitmap are preloaded in the adapter constructor :

```
// Icons bound to the rows.
mIcon1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.icon48x48_1);
mIcon2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.icon48x48_2);
```

In case the adapter have to deals with a lot of bitmap, is it still a good practice or will it be better to do something like that in the getView :

```
holder.myImage.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon48x48_1));
```

Note in my case , i can have something like 10-15 possible bitmap , but only a few will be used at same time. I'm concerned by the memory used by the adapter.

Thanks

Comment: The best way will be load image from cache.

Comment: I think you would get a "laggy" feel when scrolling your list, if you load the image in `getView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the icons are truly 48x48 pixels, they won't be that big, and since you have a known small set of them, preloading them is probably fine. I would not use that approach if:

- the images are massive, or
- the images are being loaded from places other than resources, or
- there would be more than a few dozen icon-sized images

You can always dump your heap from DDMS and inspect it with the Eclipse MAT plug-in to get a perspective on how much heap space is actually being used. Test it on Honeycomb or Ice Cream Sandwich, though, as you get better results for tracking bitmap heap consumption.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it is to wait until the list stops and then set the images for the list items that are visible. This way you will only have to load the images that are currently displayed (compared to pre-loading everything in the constructor), and it won't make the scrolling feel choppy or slow. It's a bit more work, but it will make you list really smooth with minimal memory usage.